# How to move specific data from one column to another based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Source table looks like below:

```
   Source table:
    ID      Col
    ----   --------------
     1     TAMATO / INNPU# HH55555     
     2     PATATO/9-1 666 000 0000         
     3     CARLI 1111110000/0002222000   
     4     BRINZAL          000-8888(CELL)
     5     LADY  INDAP444444444          
     6     PUMKIN   INNDP#123456789       
     7     HELLO/CELL#9-1-000-000-9900
```

I want to read record by record and would like to move the fields to another table based on following condition:

```
 1. If there is a(or more) space or any special chars(e.g. /) before the 
 number.Then move the number part(starting from number till end of the 
 string) to the new table/column.

2.For any String(record) contain "CELL" or "AP" or "PU" or "ND" or "DP": 
then, Starting from the number, move 6 chars backward and within these 6 
chars, If any String(record) contain "CELL" or "AP" or "PU" or "ND" or 
"DP" - move these records (staring from "CELL" or "AP" or "PU" or "ND" or 
"DP" till end of the string) to another table/column.
```

So my final table would look like as below.

Result table:

```
 ID      Col
----   --------------
 1     PU# HH55555     
 2     9-1 666 000 0000         
 3     1111110000/0002222000   
 4     000-8888(CELL)
 5     AP444444444          
 6     DD#123456789       
 7     CELL#9-1-000-000-9900
```

I have written the following query; however, it looks there is some problem.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @find CURSOR
 SET @FIND = CURSOR FOR SELECT col FROM Source_Table WHERE col like '%[0-
 9]%';
 OPEN @find;

  FETCH NEXT FROM @find INTO @TableName;

 DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(max)

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN


   DECLARE @ParsedData VARCHAR(5)
  DECLARE @CompVal1 VARCHAR(5) = 'CELL#'
  SET @Data =  (SELECT col FROM Source_Table WHERE col = @TableName)
     SET @ParsedData = (SELECT right(left(@Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
     @Data  ) - 1),6))

    IF (@ParsedData = @CompVal1)
    SELECT @ParsedData
   SELECT @Data, SUBSTRING(@Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Data ),
   (LEN(@Data)-1))
   FETCH NEXT FROM @find INTO @TableName;
   END;
  CLOSE @find;
  DEALLOCATE @find;
```

**Changed my query like below, still unable to achieve this:**

```
declare @result table
(

  Col varchar(max) 
 );

 declare 
  @C as cursor,

 @Col as varchar(max),
 @Data VARCHAR(max);

  set @C = cursor fast_forward for
 SELECT Col FROM Source_Table WHERE Col like '%[0-9]%';
 open @C;
  fetch next from @C into @Col;
  select @Data = @Col

 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

DECLARE @ParsedData VARCHAR(5)
--DECLARE @CompVal1 VARCHAR(5) = 'DPP# '
 --SET @ParsedData = (SELECT right(left(@Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Data  
 -- ) - 1),5))
 --IF (@ParsedData = @CompVal1)
 --SELECT @ParsedData
 --SELECT @Data, SUBSTRING(@Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Data ),
--(LEN(@Data)-1))

 SET @ParsedData = (SELECT left(@Data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Data  ) - 1))

 set @Col = @ParsedData

  insert into @result values(@Col)

  fetch next from @C into @Col;
  END;
 CLOSE @C;
 DEALLOCATE @C;

 Select * from @result
```

How can I achieve as per my Result table?

Note: My table has 100k records like this; any other way without cursor would help also.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your replacement logic?

Comment: id = 4 doesn't follow the logic you describe.

Comment: for id = 4, there is a (or more) space before the number. Hence, I'm considering starting from the number only. And, what ever, after that number I'm reading that as well( that is reading end of the staring after the number)

Comment: Why is "ATATO/" is not included for id = 2? What are the "special characters"? You need clearly state your requirements in bullet points.

Comment: Clarified the question with bullet points added.Hope this make more understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the query that covers condition 1 and "CELL" / "AP" part of condition 2.

This query uses `COALESCE` for maximum briefness, it can be replaced with `CASE` expression.

Number `1000000` is an arbitrary large number to ensure the whole string is returned by `SUBSTRING`. If your strings can be larger than 1000000 characters, change the number to a larger one.

```
DROP TABLE #TestData
CREATE TABLE #TestData( Col VARCHAR( 100 ))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
( 'PU# HH55555     ' ),
( '9-1 666 000 0000         '),
( '1111110000/0002222000   '),
( '000-8888(CELL)'),
( 'AP444444444          '),
( 'DD#123456789       '),
( 'CELL#9-1-000-000-9900'),
( 'AP    9-1-000-000-9900'),
( 'AP     9-1-000-000-9900'),
( 'asdf'),
('')

;WITH SomeNumbers AS(
SELECT 
    Col,
    COALESCE(
        -- Conditions execute in order of appearance i.e. try the first match if not matched, then then try the 2nd etc.
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX( '%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING( Col, NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%CELL%[0-9]%', Col ), 0 ), 7 )) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( Col, PATINDEX( '%CELL%[0-9]%', Col ), 1000000 ) END,
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX( '%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING( Col, NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%AP%[0-9]%', Col ), 0 ), 7 )) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( Col, PATINDEX( '%AP%[0-9]%', Col ), 1000000 ) END,
        /*
        Add your remaning conditions here using above conditions as an exmaple
        */
        SUBSTRING( Col , NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[ /][0-9]%', Col ), 0 ) + 1, 1000000 )

    ) AS ParsedNumber
FROM #TestData
)
SELECT *
FROM SomeNumbers
WHERE NOT ParsedNumber IS NULL
```

How conditions work:

`COALESCE( ...` - returns the first not NULL expression. All match conditions inside `COALESCE` are written in such way so as to return NULL if a string does not match a given condition thus allowing the next condition to be evaluated.

`SUBSTRING( Col , NULLIF( PATINDEX( '%[ /][0-9]%', Col ), 0 ) + 1, 1000000 )`:

- `PATINDEX( '%[ /][0-9]%', Col )` - looks for a pattern when the
  first character is any character is the list between [ and ]
  immediately followed by a number character. If pattern is found returns the
  character position where this pattern begins or 0 if pattern is not
  found.
- `NULLIF` returns NULL if `PATINDEX` returned 0 otherwise
  returns character position of `PATINDEX`
- `SUBSTRING` - returns the
  string beginning with character position returned by `PATINDEX` OR
  NULL if pattern was not found (and therefore `NULLIF` returned NULL).

`CASE WHEN PATINDEX( '%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING( Col, PATINDEX( '%CELL%[0-9]%', Col ), 7 )) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( Col, PATINDEX( '%CELL%[0-9]%', Col ), 1000000 ) END`

1. `PATINDEX( '%CELL%[0-9]%', Col )` - checks if there is a word "CELL" followed by a number. Other characters can appear between word "CELL" and a number. Returns the character position where the word "CELL" begins.
2. `SUBSTRING( .., .., 7 )` - grabs 7 characters starting with word "CELL". This will be the maximum possible 6 characters before the number and 7th character is the number.
3. `PATINDEX( '%[0-9]%', ...` - checks if a number character appears within 7 characters selected above.